# Show number 1 just for the first row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I make this in my SQL Server select?

Example:

```
ID  Name    Event   
------------------------------
1   Mary    Running 20/10/2017
1   Mary    Running 20/10/2017
1   Mary    Stopped 20/10/2017
1   Mary    Running 20/10/2017
2   John    Stopped 20/10/2017
2   John    Running 20/10/2017
3   Lucy    Stopped 20/10/2017
3   Lucy    Running 20/10/2017
3   Lucy    Stopped 20/10/2017
```

I'd like to show a result 1 for each ID, but only in one row

```
ID  Name    Event               Row
-----------------------------------
1   Mary    Running 20/10/2017  1
1   Mary    Running 20/10/2017  0
1   Mary    Stopped 20/10/2017  0
1   Mary    Running 20/10/2017  0
2   John    Stopped 20/10/2017  1
2   John    Running 20/10/2017  0
3   Lucy    Stopped 20/10/2017  1
3   Lucy    Running 20/10/2017  0
3   Lucy    Stopped 20/10/2017  0
```

Comment: what is the logic, what row get the 1?

Comment: Add your current query please.

Comment: I'm using a view in Analysis services, and I have to count a distinct count trought id and the same date

Comment: How are you ordering your rows here? What is your `ORDER BY` clause? Whatever it is, use the answer by @AaronDietz below and copy/paste your ORDER BY into his `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITON BY ID <paste it here>)` function.

Comment: where is your query?

Answer (score 4):

We can't give a specific answer without your query, so here is a general one.  Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to give each row a number, then use a `CASE` statement to replace all but row 1 with 0:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Event,
       CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Row]
FROM (SELECT ID, Name, Event,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RN --Add Event to the 
                                                                --partition if needed
      FROM YourTable
     ) A
```

As @JNevill mentioned, you could clean this up avoid the subquery by adding the window function directly to your `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Event,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) = 1
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END [Row]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: @EvertonGomes Nope because 1 become 1.

Comment: Could you stick the ROW_NUMBER() function into the CASE statement itself to avoid the subquery? Not sure if that is legal in tsql or not, but it feels legal.

Comment: @EvertonGomes NP happy to help

Answer (score 0):

To get distinct from both ID and the date you can use the following code:

```
SELECT ID,RIGHT([Event],10) FROM Some_table GROUP BY ID,RIGHT([Event],10)
```

OR

```
SELECT distinct ID,RIGHT([Event],10) FROM Event_table
```

If you add a row, for example:

(1,'Mary','Running 21/10/2017')

You would get two rows for ID 1 and one would give 20/10/2017 and the other would give 21/10/2017.

Is there any particular need for the column with 1's and 0's?